# Alternative to admob for flutter

Tags: flutter, admob

I am a new flutter developer.

I have an app on the play store using flutter.
When setting up admob inside the app, I placed the code inside the main.dart file.

Inside the app a user will navigate through multiple screen (roughly 10+ screens) hourly.

I didn't realize the way the admob code was setup, that a new ad was loading and showing every-time a user switched pages.

With over 50 users, some doing this up to 10 times a day, Google decided that I had broke terms of agreement and disabled my admob account.

I filed a dispute but was denied the ability to reactivate my admob account.

I am trying to figure out what my options are for monetizing my app.

I assume 1 option is to write native code and use something other than admob. Is there any other option for monetizing an app with flutter outside of admob?

Comment: I was also banned from AdMob program, even though I was very very carefully with placement the Ads. I think, Google have its own reasons for such decisions. Maybe too few revenue. Maybe something else... Could you post you experience with an other Ad company here please, after you get it to work? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not here to talk about alternatives , but admob policy has been annoying recently . I made 4 accounts so far with different package names and apps and all of them has been disabled and closed. I made sure in the last one that only 1 ad every 30 minutes is shown per user. And only 1 file ( page ) contains admob code and loads when user clicks on button and show ad before content. I've been monitoring ads request which are 10 maximum per day, but still the account has been disabled and closed .

thanks to raman raman for his answer , I will looking into them to find a good alternative

Answer (score 5):

**SEARCH THESE  PLUGINS IN PUB DEV..THEY ARE ALTERNATIVES OF ADOMB FOR FLUTTFR**

facebook audience network

ironsrc.com

adcolony

admost flutter plugin

sanjagh

nend plugin

flutter pollfish

Comment: which one would you say it's the best?

Comment: You missed applovin

Answer (score 1):

You can use admob config as usual. You only need to add https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter as a dependency and handle configs for iOS and android separately.

Comment: just to make sure I understand your correctly.

use the admob_flutter package for setting up ads.

Then use something like media.net, startapp, or inmobi inside the AndroidManifest.XML / Info.plist?

Comment: admob_flutter package acts as an interface between flutter code and native implementation of admob views. Adding this as a dependency to your pubspec.yaml  will result in having native admob libraries in gradle file and Podfile. For both platforms you'll need to get config as if it was a standard native app setup.

Comment: @Heisenbug: I don't unterstand what I neet admob_flutter for if I want to use 'facebook audience network' for example? Do I maybe need this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_audience_network